# meteor deploy on galaxy

Tags: node.js, meteor, deployment, web-deployment

I'm student learning node.js and just started developing with meteor

I was wondering if i can deploy on meteor galaxy platform, i tried doing it by terminal with the command **meteor deploy** but the deploy fails, it tells me that my account isn't allowed to deploy on meteor galaxy

I already have a meteor account, when i go to the website to activate my meteor galaxy access it requires me to enter a credit card credentials which i don't have

Is there a way to work around it and deploy projects without having a credit card ?

I managed to deploy my meteor projects successfully on heroku but i wanted to try meteor deploy platform

Comment: No, since it's a paid service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When meteor was first lunched, the galaxy service was presented for free to encourage developers to use it, since the 26 of march 2016, it became a paid service, a pay-as-you-go service, galaxy provides a container on which your app will run, you'll be charged 0.04$ per hour, approximately 29$ per month

here is a post that talks about making meteor galaxy a paid service in the [offical meteor forums](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-com-free-hosting-ends-march-25-2016/19308)